# How to perform union on table when table consists of different column name but datatype is same?

Tags: oracle

How do I perform union on two tables, when table consists of different column name but datatype is the same. Table1(id, name, location) and table2(id, name, address). Here location(varchar) and address(varchar).

I have tried the following but it returns like this when I run the query:

**Query** :

```
SELECT id, name, location, null as address FROM T1
union
SELECT id, name, address, null as location FROM T2;

**output** :

    ID  NAME    LOCATION    ADDRESS
1   1   AA        NED        NULL
2   2   BB        AUB        NULL
3   2   BB        MUN        NULL
4   3   CC        PUNE       NULL
```

but I need output like below :

```
    ID  NAME    LOCATION    ADDRESS
1   1   AA        NED        NULL
2   2   BB        AUB        NULL
3   2   BB        NULL       MUN
4   3   CC        NULL       PUNE
```

Comment: So you are not interested in single record for ID = 2??

Comment: @Tejash:   No, we interested in all the data from two tables and                                                                                 
                  I got the solution on it. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it:

```
SELECT id, name, location, null as address FROM T1
union
SELECT id, name, null as location, address FROM T2;
```

Comment: @santosh if the answer is correct, why not upvote and accept the answer?

Comment: @Jåcob: I am new here. going forward I will do.